# iOS - application states it is registered for remote notifications even though it has not been registered

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Trying to set up behavior for a function so that if the user has never signed up for push notifications, the button will show Apple's allow notifications prompt, but if the user taps "don't allow" on that prompt, every subsequent time the button will instead deeplink the user to the app's settings page.

```
  func enablePushNotifications() {
    if !UIApplication.sharedApplication().isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications() {
     //Shows Apple "Allow Notifications Prompt"
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } 
    else {
        //Deeplinks user to app settings
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
    }
}
```

the problem with this though is it returns True for isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications, even though I know for a fact I have not yet called the `registerForRemoteNotifications` anywhere else in my app. I tried setting breakpoints and checking the value.

Has anyone run into this problem previously or know how to solve it?

Comment: Have you delete your app + reset network setting? Because if your app has asked once before Apple keeps that in memory.

Comment: How do i reset my network settings? Is it by doing the thing where you change the date on your settings to a day ahead and restart your phone?

Comment: You can do so by going in general settings>rest>reset Network settings.